# Determining if a RenderSection() was called in Layout page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there a way in the Layout to determine if this will render content?

@RenderSection("Right", required: false)

That is determine if there is actually content in the View to place in the section.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Probably not exactly answering your question about testing if the section will render some content but you could test whether a section is defined and render it or provide a default content if this section is not defined:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("Right")) { 
    @RenderSection("Right")
}
else { 
    <div>Default content</div>
}
```

Comment: That's the functionality I'm looking for, just a different expression.  Something like @if(Section("Right").HasContent)...

Comment: @Paul, AFAIK there's no such functionality in Razor. Out of curiosity, what do you need this for? In what scenario do you intend to use it?

Comment: I have a two column site that is only two columns sometimes.  I want to hide the right column completely if there is not content.  However I don't want the user to have to add anything other than @Right{ some content html } no helpers or layout html that would be repeated page to page.